# Lacking smooth transition - CSS Transform on element

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a div visible on page load with some fly-in animations using jQuery. The problem is Both **(blur and scale)** are not synchronous and have some **jittery** feel when the animation is about to complete.

Thanks in advance !

Code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").css({
    "filter": "blur(0px)",
    "transition": "1s ease-in-out",
    "transform": "scale(1)",
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.container {
  filter: blur(20px);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.signin {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  background-color: rgba(56, 49, 49, 0.13);
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px ridge rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.13);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px 1px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.57);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px 1px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.57);
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px 1px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.57);
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="signin">
      <h1>Blah Blah</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="name" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" />
        <input type="text" class="class1" value="Class" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Class';}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <h2>Please Select a Template</h2>
      <div class="loop">
        <div class="item"> Template 1</div>
        <div class="item"> Template 2</div>
        <div class="item"> Template 3</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try to move 'transition: 1s ease-in-out', into css, so it will be a line inside ".container{transition:...}"

Comment: Tried it. Same as before.